# Apply map to JSON array in swift

Tags: swift, dictionary, swifty-json

Using `SwiftyJSON` I loaded a JSON array with the following structure.

```
 [
  {
  "x": 2,
  "y": 2,
  "r": 100,
  "description": {"name":"bob","institution":"NYU","technologies":[]}
  },
  {
  "x": 4,
  "y": 4,
  "r": 200,
  "description": {"name":"bob","institution":"NYU","technologies":[]}  },...
]
```

**Problem**

I want to create an object from each element in this array.

**My approach**

```
    let chartPoints: [ChartPointBubble] = json.array.map{
        ChartPointBubble(x: ChartAxisValueFloat(CGFloat($0.x), labelSettings:labelSettings),
            y:ChartAxisValueFloat(CGFloat($0.y)), diameterScalar: $0.r, description: $0.description)
    }
```

**The error**

Cannot invoke map with an argument of list type ((_) -> _)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated, not closure.

```
var chartPoints = [ChartPointBubble]()
for (index: String, subJson: JSON) in json {
   let pointBubble = ChartPointBubble(
        x: ChartAxisValueFloat(CGFloat(subJson.x.int),  
        labelSettings:labelSettings),
        y:ChartAxisValueFloat(CGFloat(subJson.y.int)), 
        diameterScalar: subJson.r.int, 
        description: subJson.description)

    chartPoints.append(pointBubble)
}
```

EDIT:
I took a look at the docs. Think best approach is to loop it. 
Also, not sure of type for your: `ChartAxisValueFloat.description`.

Comment: The README (https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON/blob/master/README.md) suggests the type is `JSON`

Comment: This gives me the error, cannot invoke map of argument list with type `((JSON) --> ChartPointBubble)`

Comment: `ChartAxisValueFloat.description` is itself a JSON array, as indicated in the OP.

Comment: In that case the code above should probably work... :)

Comment: I think you mixed `object` and `subJson`

Answer (score 0):

The error is pointing out the fact that you are passing a closure of type ()->() into the array's 'map' method. In this case, the map method needs to receive an argument of type (whateverTypeIsAlreadyInTheArray) -> (ChartPointBubble).

You might be able to fix this by:

1. adding the line "(var arrayItem) -> ChartPointBubble in" right after the first open curly brace found after the method 'map'. (I'm pretty sure you don't have to specify the type of arrayItem as it can be inferred from the items already in the array)
2. replacing '$0' with 'arrayItem'
3. returning the new ChartPointBubble you are creating

Edit: - final code should look like this

```
let chartPoints: [ChartPointBubble] = json.array.map{
    (var arrayItem) -> ChartPointBubble in
        return ChartPointBubble(
            x: ChartAxisValueFloat(CGFloat(arrayItem.x),  
            labelSettings:labelSettings),
            y:ChartAxisValueFloat(CGFloat(arrayItem.y)), 
            diameterScalar: object.r, 
            description: object.description)
}
```